# DBSet empty when referenced in separate project

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a VS2013 Solution with an MVC5 project and a Class Library project. In my Class Library, I have the context and Dbsets.  The MVC5 project works fine...the controller accesses the DBSet and fills the views.

To test a concept, I created another VS2103 solution with a Winforms project.  In the references, I referenced the Class library project.
I added a simple gridcontrol and button on the Winforms project and attempted to populate the gridcontrol with the referenced class library.
The DbSet does create, and the gridcontrol populates the column headings correctly, but the rows are empty.  In debug, I can see the Dbset has count=0 and clicking on the View Results, shows "the enumeration yielded no results".
Can anyone help with this?

The code for the Websolution is a VS2013 out of box template. The class in the class library is compressors. Nothing special there.
The code for the Winforms is:

```
 using (Data.WebAppContext db = new Data.WebAppContext())
        {
            var comps = db.SIM_Compressors.ToList();

            gridComps.DataSource = comps;

            //dataGridComps.DataSource = comps;
        }
```

Where Data.WeAppContext is the Class Library project reference.
All projects have EntityFramework 6 installed.
Thanks

Comment: did you add your connection string in that projects (web|app).config as well

Comment: Hooray!   I added the connection string to the Winforms project and I've got data.  It seems weird though, that this is required. I guess I can have a single source for my data model, but not the connections. I can live with this.  Thanks Johnny.